# Como aumentar tamanho de arquivo sql no phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Como aumentar o tamanho do arquivos sql, para importação, no phpMyAdmin, do MAMP?

Comment: Não sei exatamente qual a finalidade da pergunta.
Mas muito tempo atrás eu tinha problemas com importação de arquivos grandes no MySQL (ficava corrompido).

Com base nisso recomendo o uso do programa Heidi SQL pra importação de dados. Ele executa o arquivo em partes o que evita muitos problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Se entendi bem o que você quer fazer, você apenas precisará acessar o seu arquivo `php.ini` e alterar o valor da propriedade `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: Já fiz isso, mas não adiantou.
Quando entro na pasta de configuração, ou bin, não lembro agora, existem várias pastas com versões diferentes do php. Eu entro na mais recente, 5.6.alguma coisa, acesso o php.ini e alterei. Achei estranho não ter mudado.